# Error: Could not find or load main class org.arl.unet.UnetBoot in 2 Nodes communication

Tags: unetstack

I am a beginner and trying to use Unetstack on Windows 10 to make 2 nodes communication but I get this error in the cmd
Error: Could not find or load main class org.arl.unet.UnetBoot
Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Can you please share more information about how to reproduce? Or what are the steps you followed that resulted in this error?

Comment: I have downloaded the software and was following the Video tutorials and chapter 2 in the handbook, when I write  bin\unet samples\2-node-network.groovy I got an error saying: 
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.arl.unet.UnetBoot
and It didn't open the windows of Node A and Node B

Comment: Are you doing this from a command shell or power shell? Also, do you have java 8 installed in your windows? Which version of windows are you using?

Comment: I am writing that on Windows command prompt for windows 10 and yes I installed java 8

Comment: Can you type `java -version` on the prompt and share the output? Also, may be the actual error that you are encountering? It seems like something to do with the setting as the steps that you mentioned works on a standard Windows machine with java.

Additionally, any chance you can try it on another laptop/desktop?

Comment: it shows that 
java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)
and this is the actual error that I found on the prompt The system cannot find the path specified. Error: Could not find or load main class org.arl.unet.UnetBoot
Thank you anyway, I will try another laptop and back again to you